# No puedo cargar un JSON en un select

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Me aparece undefined repetidas veces en un select. Lo cargo de esta manera:

```js
function listarcategorias(){
    accion="listadocat";
    $.ajax({
   
            type: "POST",
            url: "../gestionweb/includes/php/getcategoria.php",
            data: {"accion":accion}, 
            

            error: function(){
                alert("error petición ajax");
            },
            success: function(data){
                
       console.log(data);
               for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                
        
                var newRow ="<option id="+data[i].idcategoria+">"+data[i].categoria+"</option>";
                  
                $(newRow).appendTo("#cat");                 
       
    
               
            }
           
        }
});}
```

asi tengo en html el select:

```html
<label class="col-sm-1 control-label">CATEGORIA</label><select id="cat"></select>
```

Y el console.log devuelve bien el array:

```js
[{"idcategoria":"1","categoria":"Fiambre"},{"idcategoria":"2","categoria":"Quesos"},{"idcategoria":"3","categoria":"general"},{"idcategoria":"4","categoria":"construccion en seco"}]
```

Alguuna ayuda?

Comment: En la configuracion del ajax, debes agregar dataType: 'json' para que funcione.

Comment: Problema resuelto..gracias

Comment: Puedo dejarlo como respuesta asi la aceptas?

Comment: @Roy Hazlo, lo iba a hacer yo explicandolo un poco: puede arreglarlo como has dicho o usando JSON.parse en la función

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Falta una configuración importante de `$.ajax` cuando se trabaja con `JSON`

```
dataType: 'json'
```

Fuente: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

PD: O como dice @Pablo Lozano, puedes decodearlo dentro del `success` con un `JSON.parse()`

Comment: Yo añadiría la explicación aquí en lugar del enlace (que está en inglés):  la función `$.ajax` no transformará la respuesta desde texto a JSON a menos que se lo digas expresamente. Si usase JSON.parse en la función success también se solucionaría el problema

Answer (score 0):

Buenas tardes apreciados amigos, también resolví este problema gracias a sus comentarios.
dejo el código. Cualquier pregunta ,mi correo es sspabonee@hotmail.com

```
  $.ajax({
                                    url:"../../ajax/tema.ajax.php",
                                    dataType: "json",
                                    type: "POST",
                                    data: ('grado='+grado

                                           ),
                                          success:function(data)
                                          {
                                               $("#asignatura").empty(); 
                                               for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
                                               {

                                                    var newRow ="<option id="+data[i].idunidad+">"+data[i].nomunidad+"</option>";

                                                    $(newRow).appendTo("#asignatura");                 

                                               }
                                               //alert(data);
                                          }

                            });
```